# two different remote server communication using python

Tags: python, sockets

this is a server code that i am running on remote server.

serv.py

```
import time, socket, sys
print('Setup Server...')
time.sleep(1)
#Get the hostname, IP Address from socket and set Port
soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_name = socket.gethostname()
ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
port = 1234
soc.bind((host_name, port))
print(host_name, '({})'.format(ip))
name = input('Enter name: ')
soc.listen(1) #Try to locate using socket
print('Waiting for incoming connections...')
connection, addr = soc.accept()
print("Received connection from ", addr[0], "(", addr[1], ")\n")
print('Connection Established. Connected From: {}, ({})'.format(addr[0], addr[0]))
#get a connection from client side
client_name = connection.recv(1024)
client_name = client_name.decode()
print(client_name + ' has connected.')
print('Press [bye] to leave the chat room')
connection.send(name.encode())
while True:
   message = input('Me > ')
   if message == 'bye':
      message = 'Good Night...'
      connection.send(message.encode())
      print("\n")
      break
   connection.send(message.encode())
   message = connection.recv(1024)
   message = message.decode()
   print(client_name, '>', message)
```

This is client code that i am running on local system.

clie.py

```
import time, socket, sys
print('Client Server...')
time.sleep(1)
#Get the hostname, IP Address from socket and set Port
soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
shost = socket.gethostname()
ip = socket.gethostbyname(shost)
#get information to connect with the server
print(shost, '({})'.format(ip))
server_host = input('Enter server\'s IP address:')
name = input('Enter Client\'s name: ')
port = 1234
print('Trying to connect to the server: {}, ({})'.format(server_host, port))
time.sleep(1)
soc.connect((server_host, port))
print("Connected...\n")
soc.send(name.encode())
server_name = soc.recv(1024)
server_name = server_name.decode()
print('{} has joined...'.format(server_name))
print('Enter [bye] to exit.')
while True:
   message = soc.recv(1024)
   message = message.decode()
   print(server_name, ">", message)
   message = input(str("Me > "))
   if message == "bye":
      message = "Leaving the Chat room"
      soc.send(message.encode())
      print("\n")
      break
   soc.send(message.encode())
```

Now if the host server is different the connection is not established. but if the host is same then it's working properly and sending texts properly. i want run this code in different server how to do please help me anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the server script, you use :

```
host_name = socket.gethostname()
```

This will probably give you "127.0.0.1".

What you need is for the server to listen to "0.0.0.0" to accept connections from everywhere.

So this will probably do :

```
host_name = "0.0.0.0"
```

Comment: It's showing connection timeout if i use host_name="0.0.0.0" or not. Basically i am running serv.py on remote server and clie.py on local system.

Comment: on your local system, try : ```netcat [host] 1234``` (replace [host] by your server IP..)
If you still have the timeout issue, then the problem is definitively server side.

Comment: it's working properly without any error. there is no problem from server side

Comment: the timeout is on the ```soc.connect(...)``` line right ?

Comment: yes, timeout is on : soc.connect((server_host, port)) from clie.py file

Comment: my guess would be an encoding issue, could you set the host IP in hard ?
Like by using : ```server_host = "xx.xxx.xxx.xx"``` instead of using ```input(...)```, just to try

Comment: I tried still showing connection timeout from clie.py file

Comment: maybe the defautl timeout is too short, I'd try something like : ```soc.settimeout(10)``` before trying to connect

Comment: i set the timeout(10) also but still it's showing "socket.timeout: timed out" from clie.py file

Comment: I'm sorry I can't see where is the problem. If you can connect using netcat, you should be able to connect using python's socket library using the same parameters.
When you fix this, please let me know what the problem was, I'm curious.
Good luck.

Comment: Yeah sure thanks...and if you get any such time of solved problem or any code then let me know.

Comment: oh, code I have, I would definitely use this if I had to make a client / server TCP stream using python : https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#examples